# EXCEL VBA Vertical Text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm just wondering if it's possible to set a text as **VERTICAL TEXT** when the **MergeCells** script is used.

The MergeCells' output resembles the Official Town Fiesta and Bonifacio Day. However, the desired output must resemble the All Saints' and All Souls' Day columns.

[image: Picture]

```
Sub MergeCells()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "123"
    
    With Selection
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .ShrinkToFit = True
        .Orientation = 90
     End With
 
    ActiveSheet.Protect "123", AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
.Orientation = 90
```

to

```
.Orientation = xlVertical
```

See the [XlOrientation enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlorientation) docs for more detail.